# ggplot2 plot area margins?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Is there an easy way to increase the space between the plot title and plot area below it (i.e., the box with the data). Similarly, I'd prefer to have some space between the axis title and axis labels.

In other words, is there a way to "move the title a bit up, the y axis title a bit left, and the x axis title a bit down"?

Comment: You can always paste some `"\n"` characters to the titles to force new lines.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You can adjust the plot margins with `plot.margin` in `theme()` and then move your axis labels and title with the `vjust` argument of `element_text()`. For example :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
qplot(rnorm(100)) +
    ggtitle("Title") +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_text(vjust=-2)) +
    theme(axis.title.y=element_text(angle=90, vjust=-0.5)) +
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=15, vjust=3)) +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm"))
```

will give you something like this :

[image]

If you want more informations about the different `theme()` parameters and their arguments, you can just enter `?theme` at the R prompt.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure what to provide to `grid::units` to make this work for the `plot.margin` argument. Turns out you have to provide a length-4 numeric to `units`. Too bad the `x` argument to `units` isn't recycled in some way. Also, you probably know this already, but worth noting/updating that `opts` is now deprecated in the latest version of ggplot2 (0.9.2+), replaced by `theme`, as is `theme_text` now replaced by `element_text`.

Comment: The order of edges for plot.margin is unit(c(top, right, bottom, left), units) if anyone else wants to save the time looking that up.

Comment: @generic_user: maybe easier to remember as noted [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/element.html): `t, r, b, l (To remember order, think trouble).`

Comment: @PaulMcMurdie Could you please tell what exactly you entered for the ```units``` argument? I cannot make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively to remember... it's just clockwise from the top: `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`.

Comment: also: `margin(t, r, l, b)`

Comment: @Mehdi.K I believe that the syntax used to be "plot.margin = grid::unit(t, r, b, l))

Best I can tell ggplot is not using 'units' anymore? I've been using plot.margin = margin(0,0,0,0, unit = 'cm') as suggested by BrianD

Comment: And the default plot margins for the theme you are using can be found by extracting `plot.margin` from the theme you are using as in `theme_grey()$plot.margin` (copied from the answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146846/what-are-the-default-ggplot2-plot-margins)

Comment: There are a lot of options for different units (other than `"cm"`). A few options are `"inches"`, `"points"`, `"lines"`. [More options here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grid/versions/3.6.2/topics/unit).

Comment: Reminds me of that particular hat the 'trilby' (t, r, l, b)