# Adjust Axis Positions ggplot2 facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am working with a plot to showcase the top 10 jail bookings in Miami over time for kicks to get more familiar with the graphing libraries.  I am running into two key issues:

1. The Title is not centered over the visual space of the graph.  It too will fall onto the graphic instead of enforcing its space.
2. The axis are either too close to the graph (when small) or if i expand the size of the plotting area, they fall off the end.

So I suppose the question is...
How do I get my axis to enforce their space on the rest of the graphic and how can I center my title.  Here is the code so far:

Here is an image: [image]

Here is the code:

```
p = d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(bookMonth), y = chargeObs, fill = factor(Charge1))) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ bookYear) +
  ggtitle("Top 10 Miami Jail Bookings") +
  labs(y="Bookings (thousands)", x="Date") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Spectral", name = "Charge") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2)),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#eaeded"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "#eaeded", size = 1),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1.25), angle = 90),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(1.25), angle = 0)
  )
ggplotly(p)
```

Here is the manipulation Code:

```
library(plotly)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rjson)
library(lubridate)

 #Read Data in.
correctionsInit = read.csv("C:\\data\\jailbookings.csv")
correctionsInit = correctionsInit %>% tbl_df()
corrections = correctionsInit

 #Number of Charges we want to display
#ie top 10.
numCharges = 10

#Questions 
corrections$BookDate = as.Date(corrections$BookDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
#
#Rework some of the labelling.
#
ChargeLUT = c("BENCH WARRANT" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "PROBATION WARRANT" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "OUT-OF-CNTY/WARRANT" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "ALIAS CAPIAS" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "ASSAULT/AGGRAVATED" = "Assault",
          "DOMESTIC VIOL WARRNT" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "GRAND THEFT/ARM/CONS" = "Grand Theft",
          "GRAND THEFT 2ND DEG" = "Grand Theft",
          "GRAND THEFT 3RD DEG" = "Grand Theft",
          "COKE/SELL/DEL/W/INT" = "Drug Traffic",
          "CONT SUB/SELL/DEL" = "Drug Traffic",
          "DWLS/HABITUAL" = "Drivers Lisence",
          "DWLS/KNOWINGLY" = "Drivers Lisence",
          "CANN/TRF/25-2000LBS" = "Drug Traffic",
          "CANN/POSN/-20/ATTEMP" = "Drug Possession",
          "DWLS/3RD & SUBS OFFN" = "Drivers Lisence",
          "NO VALID DRIVERS LIC" = "Drivers Lisence",
          "CANNABIS/POSN/0-20" = "Drug Possession",
          "COCAINE/POSSESSION" = "Drug Possession",
          "ALC BEV/DRK IN PUBLC" = "Disorderly in Public",
          "DISORDERLY CONDUCT" = "Disorderly in Public",
          "PETIT THEFT" = "Theft",
          "PETIT THEFT 1D" = "Theft",
          "ASSAULT/AGG/FIREARM" = "Armed Assault",
          "ASSAULT/AGG/DWEAP" = "Armed Assault",
          "NO VALID DRIVERS LIC" = "Drivers Lisence",
          "GRD THEFT/3D/VEHICLE" = "Grand Theft",
          "CONT SUBS/POSS" = "Drug Possession",
          "ALCOHOL/PUB/MIA BCH" = "Disorderly in Public",
          "DL/EXPIRED 6 MTHS+" = "Drivers Lisence",
          "ALC/OPN CNTR/POSN" = "Drug Possession",
          "INDECENT EXPOSURE" = "Disorderly in Public",
          "DISORDERLY INTOX" = "Disorderly in Public",
          "RESIST OFF W/O VIOL" = "Resist Officer",
          "BATTERY/AGGRAVATED" = "Battery",
          "LOITERING OR PROWL" = "Loitering",
          "ARREST WARRANT" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "ROBBERY/STRONGARM" = "Theft",
          "RETAIL THEFT/300>" = "Theft",
          "BATTERY" = "Battery",
          "BATT/DOM/STRANGLE" = "Battery",
          "DRUG PARAPHERNA/POSN" = "Drug Possession",
          "TRES PROP/AFTER WARN" = "Misdemeanor",
          "BURGLARY/UNOCC CONVY" = "Theft",
          "CANN/SELL/DEL/PSNW/I" = "Drug Traffic",
          "BATTERY/LEO/COR/FIRE" = "Battery",
          "FUG WARR/OUT O STATE" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "TRESPASS/STRUC/UNOCC" = "Misdemeanor",
          "DIS COND/ESTAB" = "Disorderly in Public",
          "RECKLESS DRIVING" = "Reckless Driving",
          "RBRY/ARM/FA/DW - PBL" = "Theft",
          "BURGLARY/OCC/DWELL" = "Theft",
          "BATTERY/AGG/DWEAP" = "Armed Assault",
          "DUI/DAM/PROP/PERSON" = "DUI",
          "ALCOHOL/CURB DRNKNG" = "Disorderly in Public",
          "DUI/BREATH LEVEL" = "DUI",
          "BATTERY/FELONY" = "Battery",
          "ASSAULT" = "Assault",
          "PROBATION VIOLATION" = "Probation",
          "CRIM MIS/1000+" = "Misdemeanor",
          "CRIM MIS/200-1000" = "Misdemeanor",
          "BURGLARY/UNOCC/DWELL" = "Theft",
          "WRIT/BODILY ATTACH" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "PANHANDLING/BEG/SOL" = "Misdemeanor",
          "CONCEALED F/A /CARRY" = "Weapons",
          "CANNABIS/POSN/20+" = "Drug Possession",
          "BURGLARY/UNOCC/PREJU" = "Theft",
          "PROST/COMMIT/ENGAGE" = "Prostitution",
          "HOLD FOR AGENCY" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "BATTERY/AGG/PREGNANT" = "Battery",
          "LSA/PROP DAMAGE" = "Reckless Driving",
          "PANHANDLE/AGGRESV" = "Misdemeanor",
          "ALCOHOL/CONSUM/STORE" = "Disorderly in Public",
          "CRIM MIS/0-200" = "Misdemeanor",
          "FA/WEAP/POSN/FEL/DEL" = "Weapons",
          "BURGLARY/UNOCC/STRUC" = "Theft",
          "UTTERING/CHECK" = "Forgery",
          "DOM VIOL/INJUNC VIOL" = "Assault",
          "GT 3RD/VEHICLE/CONS" = "Grand Theft",
          "FLEE/ELUDE PO" = "Fleeing",
          "BURG/ASLT/BATT - PBL" = "Theft",
          "BATTERY/ELDERLY" = "Battery",
          "PARK/ENT AFT HRS" = "Misdemeanor",
          "BATTERY/AGG/HRM/WEAP" = "Armed Assault",
          "STOLEN PROP/DEAL IN" = "Theft",
          "TRESP/STRUC/OCC/WARN" = "Misdemeanor",
          "HER/SELL/DEL W/INT" = "Drug Traffic",
          "BUSINESS W/O LIC" = "Bussiness Offense",
          "PETIT THEFT 2> CONV" = "Theft",
          "HOLD/CORRECTIONS" = "Misc. Warrants",
          "PANHANDLE/AGGR/OBSTR" = "Misdemeanor",
          "BATTERY/ATTEMPT" = "Assault",
          "ORGANIZED FRD/0-20K" = "Business Offense",
          "RESIST OFF W/VIOL" = "Resist Officer",
          "FLS NAME/ID/AFT ARRE" = "Other",
          "RETAIL THFT/PRI CON" = "Theft",
          "BOATING UNDER INFLU" = "DUI",
          "ATT FEL MUR/DLY WEA" = "Armed Assault"
) 
#Rename for real.
corrections$Charge1 = corrections$Charge1 %>%
  revalue(ChargeLUT)

#What are the top issues
#aside from warrants.
topCharges = corrections %>%
  filter(Charge1 != "") %>%
  filter(Charge1 != "Misc. Warrants") %>%
  group_by(Charge1) %>%
  summarise(
    totalCharge1 = n()
  ) %>%
  top_n(numCharges, totalCharge1) 

#Get data together and in good display format
d = corrections %>%
  mutate(
    bookYear = year(BookDate),
    bookMonth = ordered(months(BookDate, abbreviate = TRUE), month.abb)
  ) %>%
  filter(Charge1 != "") %>%
  filter(Charge1 != "Misc. Warrants") %>%
  group_by(bookYear, bookMonth, Charge1) %>%
  summarise(
    chargeObs = n() / 1000
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    total = sum(chargeObs)
  ) %>%
  filter(Charge1 %in% topCharges$Charge1)
```

Comment: Can you provide the data as well? Otherwise it will be difficult to diagnose the problem.

Comment: also, are you looking for a solution with the `ggplot2` or the `ggplotly`?

Comment: for reference here https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/510 is the discussion of #2 for which there is not a solution yet.

Comment: Exactly; the reason I mentioned providing the full reproducible example is that I've seen several questions here now asking for help with "ggplot", but they are creating the plot with `ggplotly` and somehow assuming that the problems are fixable from within ggplot, rather than a bug or incompatibility with ggplotly.

Comment: Rendering better with just plain ol ggplot2, running a few tests, here is the data in the mean time.  https://opendata.miamidade.gov/Corrections/Jail-Bookings-May-29-2015-to-current/7nhc-4yqn

Comment: Also see I added the manipulation code for after you read the data in, do the manipulation, and then the graphing code, should be good.

Comment: All of my issues appear to be directly related to the new bugs introduced in plotly.  @timelyportfolio can you put this in the answers, you found the issue and I'll mark as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily an answer, but this [Github issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/510) is tracking this problem and seeking a resolution.  Unfortunately, right now there is no workaround to this.

Comment: Looks like they have been actively working in this as well.  Issues are resolved now in non faceted plots.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and manually adjusted the margins of the plot.ly graph object:

```
plotly_object$x$layout$margin$l <- plotly_object$x$layout$margin$l + 30
plotly_object$x$layout$margin$b <- plotly_object$x$layout$margin$b + 30
```

Comment: That's the answer

Comment: Note: This also somehow adjusts the y axis labels, which is what I wanted. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by `plot.margin` in `theme()`, see juba's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836843/ggplot2-plot-area-margins)