# Reduce all plot margins in ggplot2 and grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, margins

I am trying to compile four graphs with `grid.arrange()` and to reduce the margins of each plot so that they are nice and compact. I would like to use `theme(plot.margin=unit(c(x, x, x , x), "cm"))` (other solutions welcome).

A similar question was asked a while ago:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836843/ggplot2-plot-area-margins)

However, `plot.margin` now requires the argument `units` which does not have a default. I could not find any explanations about what R expects in this argument. Would someone have an example?

For a reproducible example, please use the one provided in the old question.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have `unit(c(t, r, b, l), "cm")` with margin sizes at the top, right, bottom, and left, respectively. And actually there is a default value:

```
theme_get()$plot.margin
# [1] 5.5pt 5.5pt 5.5pt 5.5pt
```

An example:

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(5, 15, 25, 35), "pt"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90"))
```

[image]

Comment: To the OP: A helpful mnemonic to remember the order is ***tr**ou**bl**e*.

Comment: I realized that I had made a mistake with my parentheses, and R was showing me the following error message: ```Error in unit(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)) : 
  argument "units" is missing, with no default```
Therefore, I thought ```unit```and ```units``` were two different arguments... my bad.

Comment: @Mehdi.K, I see. It happens that your question made sense anyway as this `theme_get()$plot.margin` is, I believe, not very visible, and also may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "cm", "lines" or "points" for the units argument. Below is some example code. Just change the last argument inside theme(plot.margin=unit(c(x, x, x , 1.5), "lines") to align the 3 graphs at the beginning.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

test1 <- qplot(rnorm(100)) +
ggtitle("Title") +
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
axis.title=element_text(size=18),axis.title.x=element_text(size=14),
plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 0, 1.4), "lines"),
legend.text=element_text(size=16))

test2 <- qplot(rnorm(100)) +
ggtitle("Title") +
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
axis.title=element_text(size=18),axis.title.x=element_text(size=14),
plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 0, 1.2), "lines"),
legend.text=element_text(size=16))

test3 <- qplot(rnorm(100)) +
ggtitle("Title") +
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=16),
axis.title=element_text(size=18),axis.title.x=element_text(size=14),
plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 0, 1), "lines"),
legend.text=element_text(size=16)) 



grid.arrange(test1,test2,test3, nrow=3)
```